# Get number of concurrent users online - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, count

I would like to know the number of users logged into my ASP.NET 2.0 application.

Points to be considered:
1) Simplest way would be to use Application or Cache object to have the counts on Session start or end. However this would fail if there is a worker process recycle. Wouldn't it?

2) Should't make a difference whether the session is inproc/state server managed/ or SQL server managed.

3) Should preferably be seamless to a web-farm architecture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the built-in ASP.NET membership provider, then there's the ever-so-handy [Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.getnumberofusersonline%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method.

(Of course, it only works authenticated users...)

Comment: +1 to you. Any do's and don'ts in a web-farm architecture? Is this a machine dependant approach?

Comment: The ASP.NET membership stuff uses a provider-based architecture, so it depends which provider you use. All of the built-in ones (SqlMembershipProvider, ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider) work in a web farm, though.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net comes with several performance counters

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx

State Server Sessions Active
The number of currently active user sessions. This counter is available only on the computer where the state server service (aspnet_state) is running.

Requests/Sec
The number of requests executed per second. This represents the current throughput of the application. Under constant load, this number should remain within a certain range, barring other server work (such as garbage collection, cache cleanup thread, external server tools, and so on).

Comment: How does this approach rate when looking at a web-farm architecture? Also, what is the alternative when using InProc mode?

Answer (score 0):

You should store a user's online status in a database.  Each time a page is navigated, their LastActivity information (in the database table) is updated.

Create a SQL job that runs and logs users off if there is X amount of inactivity (and of course, if they actually do hit logout, update the database to mark the user offline)